# print data on the same line

Tags: linux, text-processing

I'm searching in a file two words using the following `grep` command:

```
grep  "ADDR|USCDB"  VLR.txt |awk -F" " '{print $3 " " $4}' > prueba.txt
```

The output is this

```
2021-03-12 14:27:15
RESULT=VLR, ADDR="573025000022";%%
2021-03-12 14:27:15
RESULT=VLR, ADDR="573025000023";%%
2021-03-12 14:27:15
RESULT=VLR, ADDR="573025000024";%%
```

What I want to achieve is to show the date and the result in the same line

```
2021-03-12 14:27:15 RESULT=VLR, ADDR="573025000022";%%
2021-03-12 14:27:15 RESULT=VLR, ADDR="573025000023";%%
2021-03-12 14:27:15 RESULT=VLR, ADDR="573025000024";%%
```

Comment: What does the input text look like? Please [edit] your question to add an example _as text_, not as a screenshot

Comment: Could you also post an extract of the originhal `VLR.txt` file? You seldom need to use `grep` and `awk` in a pipeline ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is always a `USCDB` preceding each `ADDR` line:

```bsh
awk '$2 == "USCDB" { date = $3 " " $4 } $4 ~ /^ADDR=/ { print date, $3, $4 }' input
```

This saves the date in the variable `date` whenever a `USCDB` line is found.  When an `ADDR` line is found, this value is outputted together with field 3 and 4.

I'm also a bit more strict with matching the two strings `ADDR` and `USCDB`, only matching them in particular fields and not across the whole line.

This code is untested as I had no data to test it on (there was a screenshot, but now it's gone too).

Comment: OP posted text.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Input data was shown as a screenshot, but now theres neither text nor image of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to the output record separator, `ORS`, which is implicitly appended to every print statement.

```
grep .... |
awk '{
  ORS = ORS == "\n" ? "" : "\n"
  print $3, $4
}'
```

This way will work as the two data lines come in pairs, one after the other. So for the first portion we make ORS null and newline for the second. The comma will take care of the separation between third and fourth fields.